# Trouble understanding pointers used for a linked list

Tags: c, linked-list

In a linked list, if `start` is the head node and any temporary node pointer of the same node is say `temp`, what does this assignment actually mean:

```
temp = start;
```

Does this mean that address of start is put in temp or what?

These assignment are used in many other nodes also and it's troubling me a lot.

Comment: A pointer is just a value that refers to a memory location.  The base type of the pointer tells the compiler what kind of data to expect at that memory location.  You are free to make as many copies of a pointer as you like.  It's just a number.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm gonna have to fill in some detail here, since it is only implied by what detail can be found in your question.  The basic form of a list is:

```
struct list_node {
    void *data;
    struct list_node *next;
};
```

Your question appears to be regarding two identical pointer types to a list similar to this.  *i.e.*

```
struct list_node *start, *temp;
```

Further, you state that `start` "is the head node", which I've assumed means that it's a pointer too, and it points to the head of the list.  For the sake of simplicity, I'll assume this head node is stored on the stack:

```
struct list_node head = { NULL, NULL };
start = &head;
```

And now to your actual question:

> What does this assignment actually mean
>
> ```
> temp = start;
> ```

This is simply making a copy of the pointer `start` and storing it in another location called `temp`.  Since in my example, `start` points at `head`, now `temp` *also* points at `head`.  Nothing special about it.  It's just two values named `start` and `temp` which both happen to refer to the same memory location (in this case, the area of memory where `head` is stored).

One reason you'll see this a lot in list-related code is because you often have a single pointer to the start of a list, but you also need to iterate through the list to do something with each node.  You can't just modify that one copy of the pointer because you may want to use it later.  So you just store it in another variable (in this case, `temp`) and modify that variable while iterating.  *e.g.*

```
for(temp = start; temp != NULL; temp = temp->next)
{
    // ...
}
```

> Does this mean that address of start is put in temp or what

While I've already addressed your question, I want to make a special point of addressing this question-about-your-question.

The answer is NO: The *address* of `start` would be `&start` which is a *pointer to a pointer* (in this case that would be of type `struct list_node **`).

Instead, you can say the address *held by* `start` is *stored in* `temp`.

Comment: Thank you very much for your kind and timely help  I have now understood  it .